# Why is my insert into query in Access SQL not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert

I am trying to add 2 records at a time into a table called lesson5 in Microsoft access, the code i am using is as follows, i have tried it without any fields in the insert into statement and with fields, both times i get error message missing semi colon at end of sql statement. I dont want to use a select statement or any other statements, i need to learn how to do it with insert into and values
thanks

```
INSERT INTO lesson5 
    VALUES ("SS1", "Smith", "Steven", "13 happy close", "Rotherham","M",2,64000)
    VALUES ("CC1", "Carter", "Cassie", "22 crater avenue", "F", 7,16000);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO lesson5 (CustomerID,Surname,Forename,Street,city,sex,yearsinemployment,salary) 
VALUES ("SS1", "Smith", "Steven", "13 happy close", "Rotherham","M",2,64000),
       ("CC1", "Carter", "Cassie", "22 crater avenue", "F", 7,16000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert more than 1 rows in a single statement or multiple insert statements executed as a single transaction.
Access allows you to add 1 row at a time but also execute only 1 statement at a time.
So you have to execute this:

```
INSERT INTO lesson5 (CustomerID, Surname, Forename, Street, city, sex, yearsinemployment, salary) 
VALUES ("SS1", "Smith", "Steven", "13 happy close", "Rotherham","M",2,64000);
```

and **after it is executed** then this:

```
INSERT INTO lesson5 (CustomerID, Surname, Forename, Street, city, sex, yearsinemployment, salary) 
VALUES ("CC1", "Carter", "Cassie", "22 crater avenue", "F", 7,16000);
```

but not both in a single statement in which case you will get this error message:

> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: I tried your code i get characters found after end of SQL statement

Comment: I explain this in my answer. You can't execute both inserts. Only 1 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think MS Access only allows you to insert one row at a time.  So try this:

```
INSERT INTO lesson5 (CustomerID, Surname, Forename, Street, city, sex, yearsinemployment, salary) 
    VALUES ("SS1", "Smith", "Steven", "13 happy close", "Rotherham","M",2,64000);

INSERT INTO lesson5 (CustomerID, Surname, Forename, Street, city, sex, yearsinemployment, salary) 
    VALUES ("CC1", "Carter", "Cassie", "22 crater avenue", "F", 7,16000);
```

Comment: now get error message  characters found after end of SQL Statement

Comment: @SRodgers . . . Run this as two separate statements, not one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with something like this in Access:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO lesson5 VALUES ("SS1", "Smith", "Steven", "13 happy close", "Rotherham","M",2,64000);
    INSERT INTO lesson5 VALUES ("CC1", "Carter", "Cassie", "22 crater avenue", "F", 7,16000);
END;
```